# How to show organization and individual information on a membership directory list

Tags: civimember, profile, smartgroups, directory

On a Joomla 3.9 website, I currently have a membership directory that lists all of the fields (organization name, phone, industry, city) that I want for a member (contact) with one exception:  the employee name. The membership for this client is set up at the organization level and the relationship to the individuals that belong to the organization is via an employee/employer relationship.  I created the active members of the organization via a smart group.  I need to include the employees for each organization in the directory list.  How does one go about getting past the inability of CIVICRM to not combine individuals and organizations?

Comment: How is your membership directory set up currently - through what mechanism?

Comment: If not already doing so, you may want to look at SearchKit to solve this

Comment: @Margaret - are you displaying the directory through profiles? A Joomla plugin? Something else?